# Vue.set reactivity not working for second level child object

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have answers and each individual answer has multiple comments and each comments also has multiple child comments

```
...mapState({
      comments: function (state) {
        if (this.answer_id) {
          let indexIs = state.mainAnswer.answers.findIndex(answer => {
            return answer.answer_id === this.answer_id
          })
          return state.mainAnswer.answers[indexIs].comments
        }
      }
    })
```

I am using mapState to retrieve data from store.

Here is a screenshot how it looks

[image]

The screenshot depicts there is answer with the id 112 and it has 4 comments and 4th comment has child comments.

When I am trying to add a new child comment into 4th comment it does not show up instantaneously like parent comment shows up.

I have tried like but no luck

**without Vue.set**

```
state.answers[indexIs].comments[commentIndexIs].child_comments.unshift(comment)
```

It worked for parent comments but not for child comments

**With Vue.set**

```
Vue.set(state.answers[indexIs].comments[commentIndexIs], state.answers[indexIs].comments[commentIndexIs].child_comments, state.answers[indexIs].comments[commentIndexIs].child_comments.unshift(comment))
```

One thing that I want to mention is that `[object Object],[object Object]` in screenshot is being showed when i am using Vue.set, if anybody can explain this that would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue itself is reactive to unshift(). But your object chain is so long, part of them may not be set reactive.

I have try this data:

```
export default {
        data(){return{
            a:[],
            b:[],
            c:[],
            d:['apple','banana','car'],}},
```

view:

```
<div v-for="bs in a.key">
    <div v-for="cs in bs">
        <div v-for="ds in cs">{{ds}}</div>    
    </div>        
</div>
```

this method gives reactivity:

```
mounted(){
            Vue.set(this.a, "key", this.b);
            this.b.push(this.c);
            this.c.push(this.d);
            this.d.unshift('zoo');
}
```

but this is not giving reactivity:

```
 mounted() {
            this.a.key = this.b;
            this.b[0] = this.c;
            this.c[0] = this.d;
            this.d.unshift('zoo');
}
```

please take a look which part of the object chain in your code is set by `object.key = bla`, or which array element is set by `array[key] = blabla`, because those methods are not reactive.

Also, unshift() return length instead of new element value, so your usage does not match the args of defined Vue.set(object,key,value)

Comment: What do you mean by this "you may check which properties/elements is not reactive"? How do i check,Can you please give me an example

Answer (score 1):

You should first ensure that the `child_comments` Array exists before adding an item:

```
if(!state.answers[indexIs].comments[commentIndexIs].child_comments)
  Vue.set(state.answers[indexIs].comments[commentIndexIs], 'child_comments', []);
state.answers[indexIs].comments[commentIndexIs].child_comments.unshift(comment);
```

Comment: child_comments array always exists either empty or with few objects. I have tried this this does not do "reactivity" thing

Comment: To determine where in the chain your reactivity breaks - call `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(testedObject, testedKey);` for each node in the path from `state` to `comment`. If the result contains `get` and/or `set` keys - then the node is reactive, otherwise it is not. For example - try with `testedObject = state` and `testedKey = answers`

Comment: It shows set/get, but still does not react with latest data

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a JSfiddle ? Would be much faster to check different options.